# Problema al escalar pods en Kubernetes + Flannel en servidor dedicado con CentOS 8

Tags: centos, cluster, kubernetes, pods

Hola querida comunidad

¿Cómo están?

El problema puntual que tengo es que al momento de querer escalar los pods de una aplicación, por ejemplo de 5 a 30 pods, sólo 27 de los 30 quedan habilitados.

Kubernetes tiene una configuración de un nodo maestro y el tope máximo de pods del nodo está establecido en 500, evitando así el tope por defecto de 110 por nodo.

Aquí se puede ver la lista de nodos (`kubectl get nodes`):

```
NAME     STATUS   ROLES                 AGE    VERSION
master   Ready    control-plane,master  400d   v1.22.1
```

Flannel tiene la siguiente configuración:

```
FLANNEL_NETWORK=10.244.0.0/16
FLANNEL_SUBNET=10.244.0.1/24
FLANNEL_MTU=1450
FLANNEL_IPMASQ=true
```

El nodo maestro tiene corriendo varias aplicaciones con distintas cantidades de pods por cada uno y el total aproximado entre todos suman 254 pods, lo cual sigue dentro de los 500 pods como límite.

Verificando uno de los 3 pods que no levantan (`kubectl describe pod {id_pod}`) menciona lo siguiente:

```
Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container network: failed to allocate for range 0: no IP addresses available in range set: 10.244.0.1-10.244.0.254
```

Según entiendo, a cada pod, para poder comunicarse dentro del clúster, se le asigna una IP dentro de la red establecida por Flannel.

Entonces, ¿Servirá agregar un nuevo nodo "worker" al clúster para tomar una nueva red de IPs?
Dicho de otra manera, ¿El rango de IPs de la red es asignado a todo el clúster o es por nodo?

¿Qué recomiendan antes de hacer y deshacer en la configuración actual de Kubernetes del servidor?

Comment: Para quien le sirva, realicé la misma pregunta a ChatGPT y me respondió lo siguiente:
1. El rango de IPs de Flannel se asigna a todo el clúster. 
2. Puedes crear nuevos nodos que podrían ayudar a incrementar las IPs disponibles y proveer recursos adicionales al actual clúster.
3. Otra alternativa es que, a la configuración actual, puedes cambiar la máscara de la red, pasando de 24 a 20. Esto incrementa el rango de la red de 256 a 4.096 IPs disponibles --> FLANNEL_SUBNET 10.244.0.1/20
4. Luego reinicias los pods de Flannel con el comando: kubectl delete pods -n kube-system -l app=flannel